# 2D lattice inside a coordinated plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I am trying to draw a lattice in a coordinated plane such as this but have no idea how to do it. I have searched for similar posts but cannot find anything similar to this.

[image: grid]

Comment: Your question is very similar to this question: [Numerical difference grid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574072/numerical-difference-grid)